# Secure linux distro that sends traffic through Tor

Tags: linux, security, tor

I'm looking for a live Linux distro that is secure and preserves my anonymity online.

For what I need, Tor seems to do the job – but such software requires configuration that someone who is not knowledgeable in how it works might find difficult.

I was looking at '[Lightweight portable security](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-distribution-lightweight-portable-security)' but it does not specify whether it sends all traffic through Tor. Does anyone know more information about it and/or any other such live Linux distro?

Answer (score 1):

Been doing the same search as you (my new school's security sucks).

[TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/index.en.html) fits your description.

Keep in mind though that Tor isn't a means to very safe surfing. Anyone can become a Tor node and can do a man-in-the-middle that way. You'll probably want to buy a [VPN service](http://lifehacker.com/5759186/five-best-vpn-service-providers) too, who are a tad more trustworthy than an anonymous Tor node.

Comment: Have you tried tails ? If yes, what's your experience thus far ?

Comment: I don't have the resources to do so as of now, but I can get back to you in a day or two when I can get to a decent computer.

Answer (score 1):

What digitxp is right on both counts, TAILS is a good one and Tor isn't necessarily the end all be all of anonymizing your traffic.

I recommend you check out the front page of the [Tor Wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/WikiStart#LiveCDUSB) to find a livecd distro that works for you.  Also to dig through the wiki to look for best practices.  If I remember right TAILS follows most of the ones that you'll find out there on the net, but you'll probably have to do some of your own research as well.  Your best start for that, if you do go with TAILS, is going to be the [TAILS forum](https://tails.boum.org/forum/).

My own personal recommendation is to make sure of a few things:

- Make sure privoxy is always on
- [Make sure your ip is hidden](http://rudy.mif.pg.gda.pl/~bogdro/soft/#lhip)
- [Make sure your DNS queries go through TOR](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/PreventingDnsLeaksInTor)

I'm sure I'm missing some important thing... but hopefully I helped point you in the right direction.  Check out the TOR wiki and the TAILS forum for more in depth help.

Comment: Have you checked out LPS ?

Comment: I have not, from the website I found http://www.spi.dod.mil/lipose.htm it doesn't look much different from a usual bootable distro.  Is there something I'm missing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [quantOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quantos/). It routes all traffic though Tor, and is generally hardened, but I do not know if you can make it live.